# Invert ListView without filling the ListView from the bottom

Tags: listview, qml, qt-quick

I want a ListView to invert the order of its items, so that the most recent item is at the top.
I tried to achieve this using `verticalLayoutDirection: ListView.BottomToTop`, but it makes the ListView fill up from the bottom (as to be expected, I guess).

I marked the actual bounds of said ListView in red.
[image]

How can I invert the ListView's item order and still have it fill from top to bottom? The cleaner, the better.

As requested, a bit more info:

```
ListView
{
    id: theList

    anchors
    {
        left: parent.left
        top: theAboveList.bottom
        right: parent.right
        bottom: parent.bottom
    }

    model: theModel
    delegate: theDelegate {}
    verticalLayoutDirection: ListView.BottomToTop
    clip: true
}
```

The reason WHY I need it to be inverted, is so the delegate instances know when they are at the very bottom (I can do a `index === 0` within the delegate), to set a certain state.

Comment: Well, it should be not that difficult to solve but really depends on your use case: how the list is populated, the model used and stuff like that. Just try to add some more info and the current code for the list.

Comment: I updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now solved it by setting the ListView's height-property to `contentHeight`. I originally wanted to avoid this solution due to possible layout issues (binding loops etc.), but it'll have to do for now.

Comment: This only works if the model is short enough that all the delegates fit into the view. Once `contentHeight` becomes larger than the parent of the ListView this falls apart. Did you devise a way to cope with this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

*If I understand you correctly,* First idea came to my mind is to use models and manipulate model from [C++ Qt side](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html). But this task need more patience and gives little bit overhead.

Another way is to operate your model as typical JavaScript list -- fill it, and then manually reverse.

Code for this is quite simple:

```
function swap(a, b) {
    if (a < b) {
        move(a, b, 1)
        move (b-1, a, 1)
    } else if (a > b) {
        move(b, a, 1)
        move (a-1, b, 1)
    }
}

function reverse() {
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(count/2); ++i) {
        swap(i, count-i-1)
    }
}
```

Here you can find source code for `AdvancedListModel` I wrote -- https://github.com/troyane/StackOverflow-pro/tree/master/AdvModel_qml.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to use the `ListModel`'s [insert method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#insert-method). Inserting a value in an already existing index does not squash the previous value. It shifts it.

Here's an example:

```
myModel.append({myValue: "Hello"})
myModel.insert(0, {myValue: "Goodbye"})
```

Output:

```
Goodbye
Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28536941/5414907), but following it through so that it will work for any size of model, using a spacer in the `header` component to push the delegates up to the top if there are not enough to fill the view.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    property var theModel: 2

    Component {
        id: theDelegate
        Rectangle {
            height: 100
            border.width: 2
            border.color: "black"
            color: "red"
            width: ListView.view.width
            Text {
                width: parent.width
                text: index
                font.pointSize: 30
            }
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: theAboveList
        // component exists only to complete the example supplied in the question
    }

    ListView {
        id: theList

        anchors
        {
            left: parent.left
            top: theAboveList.bottom
            right: parent.right
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }

        model: theModel
        delegate: theDelegate
        verticalLayoutDirection: ListView.BottomToTop
        clip: true

        header: Item {}
        onContentHeightChanged: {
            if (contentHeight < height) {
                headerItem.height += (height - contentHeight)
            }
            currentIndex = count-1
            positionViewAtEnd()
        }
    }
}
```